# Inconsistent model includes behavior with ActiveRecord and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

I have two models (A, B) in my rails app, and a shared module (C) between them:

```
# app/models/a.rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  includes C

  ...
end

# app/models/b.rb
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  includes C

  ...
end

# lib/c.rb
module C

...
end
```

Both of these models are managed by ActiveAdmin pages:

```
ActiveAdmin.register A do
  ...
end

ActiveAdmin.register B do
  ...
end
```

A's ActiveAdmin page works just fine.  However, B's causes my rails app to crash on startup:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant B::C
```

The app works fine when I either comment out the include in B, or remove ActiveAdmin's route setup in routes.rb.  Neither are acceptable solutions.

I realize my actual code would be more helpful, but the codebase does not belong to me, I'm afraid.  I will accept any debugging ideas that lead me to the right solution.

Comment: This error is on the `includes C` line?

Comment: @fotanus Yes. The stack trace identifies that line specifically.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can require the file that defines `C` on top of the file that defines `B`.

Comment: This actually came about as the result of such a rename.  FYI, A starts with a P, B an A, and C a V.  So if that were the case, they'd be loaded B -> A -> C.

Comment: Also, C lives in lib.  I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @jordan002 I see, have no ideas what can cause this error. I changed my question to a workaround suggestion.